# Jquery Meter, or something similar

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am in need of some way to show a Meter visually...
Something along the lines of this sort of meter:

[image]

not exact just something similar where I can set the text and the values ect.
Does anyone know of a jquery meter or something?
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fuel Gauge in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977148/fuel-gauge-in-javascript)

Comment: No I have seen the fuel gauge and it is no where near what I need and It is not customizable. I need a meter...not a gauge. Not a duplicate.

Comment: whats the difference between a meter and gauge? these look very similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Google's : http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/googleometer_chart.html

Or Create one yourself: http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: Google also has: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/gauge.html

Comment: And if you are willing to pay then fusioncharts.com are the best. Pure Javascript which renders Flash for desktops and HTML5-based charts for iPad

Comment: Yes I think the googleometer will work for me! Thanks I will play with that!

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of that comes close to this is [Teleriks Silverlight Gauge Control](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/gauge.aspx)

[image]