# Half pie diagram in cakephp and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to half pie diagram with two dynamic value.

[image]

If read value = 90% then red color should be filled upto 90% in pie-chart and rest of pie chart should be filled only 10% with the green color.

I also want ==> pointer should be changed Dynamically with the red and green aspect ratio.

Comment: and what have you tried till now ?

Comment: actully we want vote meter with two topic based on users votes aspect ratio where one topic related with red color and other with green color.Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: If you have any link related this then post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this question has been answered here: [Jquery Meter, or something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747638/jquery-meter-or-something-similar)

It's not related to CakePHP. You will most likely have to custom-code it to have the desired behavior and look.